# Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly huge RAM usage

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I've created a coding quality tool that uses reflection for some purposes. Given a codebase, I load assembly files in build folders and process them. There are like 30 thousand DLL files.

I had no problems with earlier versions of `Mono.Cecil` for this, but now, it immediately consumes like 8 Giga bytes of RAM.

I use `Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(pathToAssembly)` to load them.

What can be wrong?

Comment: "_What can be wrong?_" Based on your explanation, the answer to this question is rather obvious: the new(er) Mono.Cecil version you are using. Why does it behave differently compared to the older version(s) (according to your explanation), and whether it is intentional (even if only circumstantial) behavior or a bug i can't tell. How about checking if there is already a bug report filed in the Mono.Cecil bugtracker (if there is any); and if not, i would suggest you file one...

Comment: @elgonzo, thanks for your suggestion. I did that to see what the team says.